# Why does increasing the dimensionality of tensors enable element-wise subtraction?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Seen here: https://gist.github.com/narphorium/d06b7ed234287e319f18

This is reproduce-able code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

points = np.random.random_sample((10,2))
tf_points = tf.constant(points)
slice = tf.slice(tf_points,[0,0],[4,-1])

print tf.subtract(tf_points,slice).get_shape() #This errors out because the dimensions are incorrect

tf_points_expanded = tf.expand_dims(tf_points,0)
slice_expanded = tf.expand_dims(slice,1)

print tf.subtract(tf_points_expanded,slice_expanded).get_shape() #This works and prints (4,10,2)
```

Why is this element-wise subtraction? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the effect of tensor (or array) [Broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting).

In tensorflow/numpy, subtraction is always element-wise. Your first subtraction doesn't work because operands have shapes `(10,2)` and `(4,2)`, which are not **compatible**. When you expanded the dimensions, the shapes became compatible.

The shapes of the operand matrices may be different but need to be compatible for an element-wise operation to work.

For shapes to be compatible, the shapes are aligned at the trailing/last dimension, and then every 2 corresponding dimensions must be compatible. Two dimensions are compatible if :

> 1. They are equal, or
> 2. One of them is 1 (a "degenerate" dimension)

For example `np.zeros((5,1,2)) - np.ones((3,1))` works, because the shapes are compatible :

```
5 1 2
  3 1
    ^ aligned at the trailing dimension
```

The way it works is that for each dimension (starting from the last), the matrix of smaller size in that dimension will be *repeated* along that dimension to match the other matrix. In this example, for the last dimension, the `(3,1)` matrix needs to be repeated at the last dimension to be `(3,2)`. Then for the second-to-last dimension, the `(5,1,2)` needs to be repeated to become `(5,3,2)`. Finally, the `(3,2)` matrix is repeated 5 times along a new first dimension, becoming `(5,3,2)` too. Element-wise subtraction is then performed normally.

In your example, doing subtraction on non-compatible shapes `(10,2)` and `(4,2)` gives an error. But after expanding their dimensions to `(1,10,2)` and `(4,1,2)`, they became compatible according to the rules above :

```
1 10 2
4  1 2
```